# How was this marked as a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I'm wondering how (not why - that's rather obvious :-) but *how* [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984736/passing-floats-to-oracle-from-pdo-using-bindparam-raises-ora-01722) was successfully marked-as-dup? IIRC whenever I use Mjolnir I have to reference a question which has an accepted or upvoted answer. In this case the [referenced dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943562/passing-float-to-oracle-db-from-php-pdo-ora-01722) has no answers. I'm not complaining, just wondering about the how's and why's of this.

Comment: Because both questions were made by the **same** user. I can't find the link right now (surely someone will post it soon...), but as a gold badge user I have been able to mark questions as *duplicate* when the OP keeps asking the same question again and again, even if the original one has no answer or upvotes.

Comment: How ironic this question got closed as duplicate.